# Request.Unvalidated has the wrong argument to find a nested TextBox in a formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-4.5

It's my first encounter with validating a TextBox. I'm using the following code as described on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx) to disable request validation and then to manually check the unvalidated user input.  My TextBox is nested in a formView and my argument doesn't seem to work. How can I unvalidate the nested TextBox? What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          var userComment = Request.Unvalidated(FormView3.FindControl("aboutTextBox")); 
        // Has the wrong arguments. How can I unvalidate the nested control?

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FormView3.FindControl("aboutTextBox")));
        // Selectively allow <b> and <i>
        sb.Replace("&lt;b&gt;", "<b>");
        sb.Replace("&lt;/b&gt;", "</b>");
        sb.Replace("&lt;i&gt;", "<i>");
        sb.Replace("&lt;/i&gt;", "</i>");
}
```

Comment: So far I've been able to use this to find the control: var userComment = Request.Unvalidated(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(FormView3.FindControl("aboutTextBox"))); But it doesn't work as it should because the textbox is still being validated and I get this error:A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client....

Comment: I can't find any instructions on how to unvalidate a nested textbox using the Request.Unvalidated of asp.net 4.5

Answer (score 0):

To disable request validation, Add this in page directive at .aspx page (1st line)

```
ValidateRequest="false"
```

And this in web.config under `<system.web>`

```
 <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

then try to get txtbox value normally

```
var userComment = ((TextBox)View1.FindControl("aboutTextBox")).Text;
```

By turning off the request validation, you need to make sure that you will validate user input yourself!

Comment: That will disable the validation of all requests. This is not what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to disable one particular control on a page using the Request.Unvalidated, the new feature of asp.net 4.5.

Comment: Don't think Request.Unvalidated will work with server controls (web forms)